# Rocket simulation with Python: syntax error

Tags: python, physics

I have to implement a python rocket simulation for my physics class, and I get an "invalid syntax" error. It is probably a really stupid mistake but I'm stuck… Here's the line that gets the error. It's in a for loop that goes from 0 to timesteps (which is about 10 000):

```
acceleration[i] = (F_ext + velocity_rel[i]**2 * area_nozzle * density_water)/mass_total[i]
```

I get "invalid syntax" pointing at the acceleration, which is an array defined earlier:

```
acceleration = numpy.zeros(timesteps+1,dtype='d')
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Post a bit more of your code. If a syntax error points at the start of the line it probably means unclosed parentheses from the line before.

Comment: Please show the code pertaining to the entire `loop` (i.e. `for i in ...`), and also please share the entire `traceback`.

Comment: I know this isn't a direct answer to your question, but a good way to find the cause of simple syntax errors is to paste your code into a good IDE like PyCharm. In fact it'll make a lot of things easier.

Comment: 99% chance that you missed a parenthesis on the previous line. You need to show more of the code.